# YQL rss feed from wordpress set limit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rss, blogs, yql

I feel really stupid but I just can't figure out how to add a limit on my YQL rss feed I here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ7sA/14/) - I only want to show the last 2 (most recent) blog posts

```js
YUI().use('node', 'gallery-yql', function(Y) {
  new Y.yql('select * from rss where url="http://caremonkeys.co.uk/feed/"',
  function(r) {
    if (r.query) {
      if (r.query.results) {
         var res = Y.one('#results'), content = '<ul><li></li>';
         Y.each(r.query.results.item, 
            function(v) {
              var the_link=v.link;
              var the_title=v.title;
              var the_desc=v.description;
              var the_image=v.image;
              var the_cat=v.category;
content += "<li class="+the_cat+"><a href="+the_link+">"+the_title+"</a>"+the_desc+"<img src="+the_image+"></li>";
                });
         content += "</ul>";
         res.setContent(content);
}}});});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">Loading...</div>
```

- any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this,change no_items to wordpress limit,

YUI().use('node', 'gallery-yql', function(Y) {
  new Y.yql('select * from rss where url="http://caremonkeys.co.uk/feed/"',
  function(r) {
    if (r.query) {
      if (r.query.results) {
         var res = Y.one('#results'), content = '<ul><li></li>';

         //
           var no_items= 2;
           var item = r.query.results.item;
           for(var i=0;i<no_items;i++){  

               var title = item[i].title;  
               var link =  item[i].link;  
               var desc =  item[i].description;  
               var the_cat = item[i].category;
               content += "<li class="+the_cat+"><a href="+the_link+">"+the_title+"</a>"+the_desc+"<img src="+the_image+"></li>";

           }

         //
         content += "</ul>";
         res.setContent(content);
}}});});
```